# 2 x 90 Ah 12v deep cycle batteries in series runs 77-90w for under 20 minutes. Why?

Tags: batteries, watts, ups, 24v, backup

I am trying to understand the maths here. I have 2x90Ah 12v batteries in series (24v) and they are powering my computer. The peak power is 120w while the computer is shutting down during a power loss. I get less than 20 minutes run time.

As far as I can tell, when I do the calculation of how many amps it draws I get somewhere around 1A at idle and up to 5A when it is in full draw.

Am I correct to assume that if I am right, at full draw at 5A I should be getting many hours of power out of it? Or at least an hour+? Are my calulations wrong or is there something else going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118846/discussion-on-question-by-eric-the-red-2-x-90-ah-12v-deep-cycle-batteries-in-ser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments, it sounds like you observed a 1V drop in the wiring under moderate load. The number one problem I see with inverters (A UPS is basically an inverter) is that the DC wiring is too small. As current flows through this narrow wire, voltage drop occurs. This is especially obvious during heavy loads. The inverter (or UPS) doesn't know that the voltage drop is due to wiring. It thinks the battery voltage is low and gives a warning or shuts down.

The best way to avoid this is to use adequate sized wiring. The size depends on both the length of the wire run and the diameter of the wire.

Let's go through a quick example. If you have a total of 20 feet (including all wire, both directions plus whatever wire connects the two batteries) of 12AWG wire, how much resistance is that and what voltage drop will it cause?

First, find the resistance of 12AWG wire online in a table:
http://bnoack.com/index.html?http&&&bnoack.com/data/wire-resistance.html

That table shows 1.7 Ohms for 1000 feet of AWG 12 wire.

So for 20 feet that will be 1.7 * 20 / 1000 = 0.034 or 34 mOhms.

Now let's say the current is about 6 Amps (to approximate your 120 Watt load, and allowing for efficiency of the UPS). The voltage drop will be equal to the wire resistance * current:

6 Amps * 0.034 Ohms = 0.2V

That may or may not be enough to cause a problem at 6 Amps. But for a larger load, like 20 or 30 DC Amps, it would definitely be problematic. This is why even small inverters typically have large DC wires.

Moving the batteries close to the inverter also helps a lot.

A final note: The termination of the wire (crimp, solder lug, etc) can often become a point of high resistance, especially when currents are high (10, 20, 50, 100 Amps). It is a good idea to monitor the temperature of high current connection points to make sure everything is OK. They can actually get so hot they become a fire hazard.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have a 50 amp breaker in line. Is that too big?

Comment: You mean a DC breaker? Usually you want to size your breaker and your wire together. You would do this using an ampacity table (link below). If the breaker or fuse is 50 Amps then you should be using 8AWG or 6AWG. The purpose of a fuse or breaker is to make sure the wire does not get too hot no matter what faults may occur. So the breaker is supposed to trip before the insulation on the wire starts to smoke or burn somebody. https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/

Comment: 50 Amps at 24V implies around 1200 Watts of DC input power which will get you around 1000 Watts of AC power. I don't know the output power rating of your UPS. If it is capable of putting out 1000 Watts, then you would probably want to use AWG 6 wire unless the wire distance is very short, and you could use AWG8. Go through the voltage drop calculations.

Comment: The UPS is rated at 1500W. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: So I bought a fresh battery so now I have 2 fresh ones, I replaced all of the wiring with 10awg and made it as short as possible, soldered all the connections, done everyting I can to make the connections more efficient and I now have a 30 minute run time. What the heck is going on here?

Comment: Says 60 watts, 100% charged, 30 minutes of runtime.

Comment: @EricTheRed - Hi, You've started a [new question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/550429/2-x-90ah-batteries-in-series-provide-30-minutes-runtime-for-60-90-watts-why-pr) to ask why you are still having problems. Therefore it isn't allowed to also ask about it *here* as then they are duplicates (the new question & these new comments). So please pick one - either delete the new question, or delete your 2 recent comments above (which is what I recommend). Thanks!